# Having a problem with rewriting invoke function inspired by underscore library

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, methods, underscore.js

I'm a beginner and trying to rewrite an underscore function [`_.invoke`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#invoke).
I'm trying to make the function so it returns an array with the results of calling the method on each value in the collection.

```
_.invoke = function(collection, methodName) {
  var result = [];
  if (Array.isArray(collection)) {
    for (let i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
      methodName.call(collection[i])
      var value = collection[i][methodName]
      result.push(value)
    }
  }
  return result
}
```

I think my problem lays in this line:

`methodName.call(collection[i])` - would like to invoke method on an object `collection[i]` but I would like to pass some arguments should they be included in the unit test.

I've tried so far utilizing the test : `typeof(methodName) === "function"` and writing a function that would test whether the method is a function.

Comment: Thank you guys a lot, it took me a while but i resolved the issue. The test weren't passing because I have jumped into conclusion and have not taken into account that said collection could be either an array or set of objects and both scenarios should have been approached. Object.values() and rest param ( thanks mplungjan)did the rest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```js
const myArr = [
  { cons:function(args) { return args } },
  { cons:function(args) { return args["bla"] } },
]

const _ = {};
_.invoke = (collection, methodName, ...args) => !Array.isArray(collection) ? [] : collection
.filter(item => typeof item[methodName] === 'function')
.map(item => item[methodName].apply(item, args));

const res = _.invoke(myArr,"cons",{"bla":"hello"})
console.log(res)
```

Here is a more performant version if you need speed over a lot of entries

```js
const myArr = [
  { cons: function(args) { return args; } },
  { cons: function(args) { return args["bla"]; } },
];

const _ = {};
_.invoke = (collection, methodName, ...args) => {
  const result = [];
  if (!Array.isArray(collection)) return result;

  for (let i = 0, len = collection.length; i < len; i++) {
    const item = collection[i];
    const method = item[methodName];

    if (typeof method === 'function') {
      result.push(method.apply(item, args));
    }
  }

  return result;
};

const res = _.invoke(myArr, "cons", {
  "bla": "hello"
});
console.log(res);
```

Comment: I wouldnt go functional here (that was my first try), because it will suffer performance on big collections since you have to loop twice and allocated an intermediate filtered array.

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev I added a second version. Is that better?

Comment: looking good now

Answer (score 1):

Here you can invoke with arguments.

```
_.invoke = function(collection, methodName, ...args) {
  if (!Array.isArray(collection)) {
     return [];
  }
  const out = []; 
  for(const item of collection){
    if(typeof item[methodName] === 'function')
      out.push(item[methodName].apply(item, args));
    }
  }
  return out;
}
```

To test that all items have a method:

```
const collection = [...];
const allHaveMethod = _.invoke(collection, 'method', 'arg1', 'arg2').length === collection.length;
```